# Reference on high dimensional polytopes with E8 symmetry

Tags: reference-request, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, lattices

I'm starting to work with high dimensional polytopes. I am interested in uniform polytopes of 16-dimension and of 8-dimension (especially Elte and Gosset polytopes that have E8 symmetry).

Unfortunately, while on 8-dimensional polytopes we still have some references I struggled to find anything on 16-dimensional polytopes. Is there a standard catalogue with all the known propreties of higher dimensional polytopes?

Please let me know if you have some exahustive reference.

P.s. I was given to understand that there is a written text by Norman Johnson on uniform polytopes, but I could not find it on the web. Please let me know if you have any news on that text.